# Unable to add more than one person to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The code below is supposed to complete the following tasks once the first and last name fields are entered:

1. Assign the index number to the person,
2. Populate that information in a list form

Below is the code that I have so for:

```
$("volunteerList").value = null;
for(var i = 0, vString = i + 1 + ". " + volunteerArray[i] + "\n"; i <  volunteerArray.length; i++){
  $("volunteerList").value+=vString;
}
```

The problem that I am having is that it is not clearing out and no matter what the next name I enter is, it populates the same name as the first entry.

I'm not sure what I am missing from this code to allow for the next person to be entered with the next index number that follows, in this case, either 2, 3, 4, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: jQuery uses `.val()` not `value = `

Comment: You also understand that the vString is only being set once, right?  The first part of the for loop is the initialization step, which only runs once per for loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is your loop. You're setting the value for vString during the initialization of the for loop, so it does not get updated each iteration.

```
$("volunteerList").val() = null;
for(var i = 0; i <  volunteerArray.length; i++){
  vString = i + 1 + ". " + volunteerArray[i] + "\n"
  $("volunteerList").val($("volunteerList").val() + vString);
}
```

Comment: `val()` is the getter.  `val(newValue)` is the setter.

Comment: Thank you, as always it was something simple that I was not seeing.  Moving the vString section to be inside the loop instead of on initialization worked.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map off of jQuery or the Array to build the list of strings you want to set as the value, and join them on empty string.

```js
var volunteerArray = [ 'Jim', 'Sarah', 'Lance' ];

$("#volunteerList").val($.map(volunteerArray, function(element, index){
  return ++index +'. '+ element +'\n';
}).join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="volunteerList"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you missing an id or class specifier in your jquery?

```
 $(".volunteerList").value =null;
        for(var i=0,vString=i+1+". "+volunteerArray[i]+"\n";i< volunteerArray.length;i++){
            $(".volunteerList").value+=vString;
        }
```